# Get sorted most common objects from an array of hashmaps in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm looking to get the sorted most common results from an array containing hashmaps. The hashmap data is non-numerical so:

```
line_value = {'date' => date, 'name' => name, 'url' => url }
```

where I can grab the most common urls. I considered using SQL to grab the counts, sort them and be done with it, but I think there is probably a faster way to do it in straight ruby since the array and hashmaps are not in a database and would need to be put there to begin with.

So I'm looking for non-SQL methods to do this. Note, I'm not just looking for the most common result (singular) but the top 5 or 10 common results.

Answer (score 0):

```
urls.map {|u| u["url"]}.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|k,v| k[v] += 1; k}.rank.sort_by {|k,v| v}.last(5).reverse
```

Or:

```
urls.group_by {|k|{ :u => k["url"], :q => 0}}.map {|k,v| k[:q] = v.count; k}.sort_by {|k| k[:q]}.last(5).reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
most_common_urls = line_value['url'].sort[0..9]
```

Change

> [0..5]

to whatever number you need.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to build up a count of the unique urls in your array. I much prefer `each_with_object` to `inject` for this (you don't have to return the hash at each step):

```
url_count = items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |item, count|
  count[item['url']] += 1
end

# => {'example.com' => 1, 'facebook.com' => 4, 'twitter.com' => 2, ...}
```

Then you want to turn this into is an array of the keys, sorted by the values. Using `Array#sort_by` will do quite nicely, but it sorts in ascending order. You could take the *last* N items, and reverse them:

```
top_urls = url_count.keys.sort_by!{|url| url_count[url]}.last(5).reverse!
```

or you could negate the count so that the highest numbers are sorted to the front:

```
top_urls = url_count.keys.sort_by!{|url| -url_count[url]}.first(5)
```